# PHP/MYSQL BETWEEN Numbers Looping same function

Tags: php, mysql, loops, between

I've been trying to solve this for days and I'm sure the right person could do it easily.

```
 <?php              
     displayMatrixNumbers();
?>
<?php
    function displayMatrixNumbers()
    {
        $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
               
        $statement = "SELECT number, association, image_file, skeleton, sound, colour, comments ";
        $statement .= "FROM num_image ";
        $statement .= "ORDER BY number ";
       
        $sqlResults = selectResults($statement);
       
        $error_or_rows = $sqlResults[0];
       
        if (substr($error_or_rows, 0 , 5) == 'ERROR')
        {
            print "<br />Error on DB";
            print $error_or_rows;
           
        } else {
           
            $arraySize = $error_or_rows;
       
            for ($i=1; $i <= $error_or_rows; $i++)
            {
                $number = $sqlResults[$i]['number'];
                $association = $sqlResults[$i]['association'];
                $image_file = $sqlResults[$i]['image_file'];
                $skeleton = $sqlResults[$i]['skeleton'];
                $sound = $sqlResults[$i]['sound'];
                $colour = $sqlResults[$i]['colour'];
                $comments = $sqlResults[$i]['comments'];
                               
                print "<div id='mcnumbers-container'>";
                print "<h3>".$number."</h3>";
                print "<p><img id='mcnumber-image' src='images/matrix/".$number. ' - '.$association.".jpg'>";
               
                print "<br />".$association."</p>";
                print "</div>";
 
               
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Do I need the row count I have inserted? Could it come in handy at some point?

The main objectives I'm trying to complete are:

1. Simplify my code as much as possible.
2. I want to use this code and paste the function displayMatrixNumbers() 100 times in different DIV Tabs or perhaps using a function is not the best practise?

   In pastebin I want to change the line: `$statement .= "ORDER BY number ";` to `$statement .= "BETWEEN 00 to 09 ORDER BY ASC ";` or something like that?

I need to however change the BETWEEN two numbers from '00 to 09' to '10 to 19' to '20 to 29' and so on for the project I'm building.

In short, is it possible to change just the BETWEEN Numbers from outside the function. That way 'some how' I can enter the two numbers `$lownum = '00'; $highnum = '09';`  and then `$statement .= "BETWEEN $lownum to $highnum ORDER BY ASC "`

Say I have 3 DIV's

```
<div id="div1">
<?php displayMatrixNumbers(); ?> /* This one displays 00 to 09 */
</div>
<div id="div2randomID">
<?php displayMatrixNumbers(); ?> /* 10 to 19 */
</div>
<div id="div3">
<?php displayMatrixNumbers(); ?> /* 20 to 29.. and so on */
</div>
```

Say I have 100 div's.. How can I specifically tell each one to show only the results I want without creating 100 separate .php pages? I know I need some kind of loop that edits just the BETWEEN numbers but no idea how?

I properly have to rewrite this to make it clearer but my brain is fried and I hope someone can understand what I'm meaning. Even if you need me to clarify something please ask.

I'm new at all this and if it's not all PHP I have used I apologize and would like to be shown how to accomplish this with PHP.

Cheers,
Dan :)

Comment: Don't use a paste bin for your code, rather include the critical portions of your code in the actual question.  Links can go away in the future, and it makes it harder to read your question right now.

Comment: You could add arguments to the displayMatrixNumbers function such as function displayMatrixNumbers($from = 0, $to = 9) { ... } and then call displayMatrixNumbers(0, 9) .... displayMatrixNumbers(10, 19) etc

Comment: Dont use pastebin, add your code to the question in future. Pastebins disappear, and that makes the question useless to others that may find it looking for solutions to similiar problems. I pasted the code ito your question for you

Comment: TimBiegeleisen and @RiggsFolly thanks.. no worries about the Pastebin.

HelloSpeakMan are you able to expand on how to do that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the LIMIT sql clause you can accomplish this quite easily

```
    $DOCUMENT_ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

    $statement = "SELECT number, association, image_file, 
                         skeleton, sound, colour, comments
                  FROM num_image 
                  ORDER BY number
                  LIMIT $start, 10";

    $sqlResults = selectResults($statement);

    $error_or_rows = $sqlResults[0];

   // I am not sure what library you are using to access your database
   // but there must be a better way of identifying errors
   // than this next piece of code
    if (substr($error_or_rows, 0 , 5) == 'ERROR')
    {
        print "<br />Error on DB";
        print $error_or_rows;

    } else {

        foreach ( $sqlResults as $row ) {
            $number       = $row['number'];
            $association  = $srow['association'];
            $image_file   = $row['image_file'];
            $skeleton     = $row['skeleton'];
            $sound        = $row['sound'];
            $colour       = $row['colour'];
            $comments     = $row['comments'];

            print "<div id='mcnumbers-container'>";
            print "<h3>".$number."</h3>";
            print "<p><img id='mcnumber-image' src='images/matrix/".$number. ' - '.$association.".jpg'>";

            print "<br />".$association."</p>";
            print "</div>";

        }
    }
}
```

And then you call it using the start row that you want to use

```
<div id="div1">

<?php displayMatrixNumbers(0); ?> /* This one displays 00 to 09 */

</div>
<div id="div2randomID">

<?php displayMatrixNumbers(10); ?> /* 10 to 19 */

</div>
<div id="div3">

<?php displayMatrixNumbers(20); ?> /* 20 to 29.. and so on */

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a class to solve perpetual displays. Classes hold data that can be stored and reused.

```
class display {
    private $count = 0;
    public function display(){
        for($i = $this->count; $i < $this->count + 10; $i++){
            echo $i;
        }
        $this->count += 10;
    }
}
$display = new display();

$display->display(); //prints 0 - 9
$display->display(); // prints 10 - 19
$display->display(); //prints 20 - 21
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but I'm a bit perplexed how to apply this. I mean RiggsFolly the way he set it out I can understand how to apply it, Is yours a count and continues as long as I want or can I pull out the display() and put it anywhere, if so how do I specify what display is what number to number?